# SQLServer Query Store not saving failed queries run by SP_ExecuteSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, query-store, timeout

We are on SQL Server 2016

Query Store is activated on the database in question.

We have had some timeout problems reported on a nightly batchjob, and we have located the query in question.

The query is from a .Net application, generated by some framework

I have also found the query in Query Store.
But if i use 'tracked queries', all executions are reported as good, no timeouts (and no errors)

And if i query the QueryStore for that particular queryID, all executions has result 'Regular'

If i setup an extended events session to catch timeouts, the timeouts of the query is indeed collected and i can see that the actual call of the query is done with

`EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'querystring'`

does this somehow cheat the querystore into thinking it is ok, no matter what the result ?

regards

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this somehow cheat the querystore into thinking it is ok, no matter what the result ?

Queries executed with `sys.sp_executesql` can definitely be logged in the Query Store as "Aborted" or "Exception."  Here's a small repro.  First I created a database with impractical Query Store settings:

```
USE [master];
GO
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS [278067];
GO
CREATE DATABASE [278067];
ALTER DATABASE [278067] SET QUERY_STORE = ON;
ALTER DATABASE [278067] 
SET QUERY_STORE 
(
    OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE, 
    DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 30, 
    INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES = 1
);
GO
USE [278067];
GO
```

Then I ran some .NET code that exercised the following scenarios:

1. Run a normal successful query
2. Run a query that errors out (in this case, it was a divide by zero)
3. Run a query that returns millions of rows, and then cancel client-side before all the results have been consumed
4. Run a query that returns millions of rows, and then close the connection before all the results have been consumed
5. Run a query that gets blocked, and experiences a server side lock timeout

Here's how the came through in the Extended Events "rpc_completed" event:

[image: Screenshot of extended event output, showing two oks and three aborts]

I embedded a comment of `/* Track Me */` in each of the queries so I could find them in the query store:

```
SELECT
    qsrs.execution_type,
    qsrs.execution_type_desc,
    qsrsi.start_time,
    qsrsi.end_time,
    qsqt.query_sql_text,
    qsp.query_plan
FROM sys.query_store_plan qsp
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query qsq
    ON qsp.query_id = qsq.query_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text qsqt
    ON qsqt.query_text_id = qsq.query_text_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsrs
    ON qsrs.plan_id = qsp.plan_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats_interval qsrsi
    ON qsrsi.runtime_stats_interval_id = qsrs.runtime_stats_interval_id
WHERE
    qsqt.query_sql_text LIKE '%Track Me%'
    AND qsqt.query_sql_text NOT LIKE '%sys.query_store_plan%';
```

[image: Screenshot of query store query results]

As expected, we see Regular, Exception, and then three Aborted queries.

All that is to say that I don't think the discrepancy can be explained by the application's use of `sys.sp_executesql`.

If you could elaborate more on:

- your query store settings (perhaps the queries experiencing timeouts aren't being logged)
- what specific kind of timeout the query experienced (client side connection or command timeout, lock timeout, something else)
- the extended event you used to identify the timeout

Then you might be able to get some more help tracking this down.

Comment: thanks josh
i never got the mail about your reply, thats why i havent answered before
i will try to examine further, 
just ran your test example with same results

Comment: Josh was completely right, reason for us not finding, was that it was not exactly the same query being run, the ORM had created a slightly different query, and when we realized that it was also found in QS